# My jQuery Code isn't working I've searched everywhere

Tags: jquery

I have searched both google and SO for this, but haven't been able to find an answer, I have this jQuery code:

```
<head>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "#show" ).click(function() {
  $( "#content" ).fadeToggle( "slow", function() {
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="show">
   Show more/less</button>
<div id="content">
<p>Blah blah blah</p>
</div>
</body>
```

But it doesn't work. I am very new to jQuery so wouldn't really know where to start. 
Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jofish999/hs6v06bf/

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear not to have imported the jQuery library, otherwise your code is fine.
Add this code to your file, between your `<head>` tags:
    `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

jQuery is written in javascript, and the above file is simply a javascript file ‘enabling’ you to use jQuery (as it is not automatically included in web browsers like HTML, CSS and javascript)
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much that was the reason it didn't work that fixed it thank you!!!!! :) :)

Answer (score 2):

working: http://jsfiddle.net/hs6v06bf/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#show").click(function () {
        $("#content").fadeToggle("slow");
        //you dont really need the callback in this case, so I removed it.
    });
});
```

dont forget to add jquery library, since `$(element_selector)..` stuff works only if you have jquery imported.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked to, +1 if I could :)